# HTC One SV: Preditive dictionary turns "I was" into "I WAS" every time. How can I turn this off?

Tags: htc, htc-sense, auto-correct, text-prediction

Whenever I type "I was", the preditive dictionary chooses "WAS" as the first choice, rather than "was". However, it does not do this if I type "was" on its own, only if it follows "I." Obviously this is very annoying when typing out quick replies on my phone. I have next word prediction turned off, "WAS" does not appear in my dictionary so cannot be deleted. Why is it doing this only with this phrase, and how can I turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

In your keyboard settings there should be a "My dictionary" or "My words" or something similar, in there should be all of the words you have added to AutoCorrect, if "WAS" is there, delete it, if not add "was".

Comment: I entered was into the dictionary, deleted it and now it seems to have fixed itself. Thanks!

Comment: No bother, glad it worked. Remember to select this as the answer.